# Is Adafruit LPD8806m LED strip waterproof?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, led

I want to make a holiday light display with the LPD8806 5M strip.

Are these waterproof? Or do I need to mount them in a waterproof enclosure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about whether a piece of hardware is waterproof or not.

Comment: belongs on electronics stackexchange.

Comment: sorry. I will move it there. Came here from a google link so I didnt know where it was actually posting.